# OpenLayers ScaleLine not showing properly

Tags: openlayers

I have a minor problem with my ScaleLine, the code isnt more then

```
this.scaleline = new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine();
map.addControl(this.scaleline);
```

And this should show everything just fine, as long as you initate it where the map is being initated (I have tried placing it at different places, but same result).

All I do get is
[image: ScaleLine]

And its logic works just fine, and when I read OpenLayers, thats all you need to have it fully working.

What Im missing, is the "line" between the numbers and around (to make it look like a scale). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue, I totally forgot that in default/theme there's a css which does some magic for the scaleLine.

So I figured I write it here and now, incase someone else forgets about the default CSS.

Comment: In particular the file theme/default/style.css from the OpenLayers package must exist, relative to the location of OpenLayers.js.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access OpenLayers.js through net directly? or did you save it in your pc?
Because i have found some glitches when accessing it through net. 
See if that helps. 
Cheers.

Comment: I'm accessing it locally on my PC.

Comment: map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine()); try defining it directly. Sorry, don't know any other reason why it is happening so.

Comment: Does the exact same thing.

Comment: <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"> try using this lib instead of local then. if that is working, then maybe your openlayers local pc lib is unstable.

Comment: I highly doubt that would be the problem. But I gave it a try and like I thought from first time, thats not the issue :-)